# Do I need Xcode to setup certain packages?

Tags: xcode, react-native, npm

I noticed when installing [react-native-splash-screen](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-splash-screen) and a few other packages, it mentions in the installation process to change some things in xcode. Do I have to have xcode if I want to include these things in a published product?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to publish your app for ios platform, yes you do.

React Native team is trying to make third-party library installations as easy as it can be but sometimes you still have to do some extra steps to make it work.

With version 0.60 there is a new auto linking feature

[Auto Linking Documentation](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md)

If libraries you're using is demonstrating manual linking steps, you probably don't have to do those steps, but you still have to do the extra setup steps.

These extra steps are these in your case: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-splash-screen#third-stepplugin-configuration